# How to reference multiple ObjectId in array in MongoDB?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I have a question, How i can reference multiple ObjectId from array in Mongoose (MongoDB) ?

Post Model:

```
import mongoose, { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const Post = new Schema({
  ...
  contributer: [
    {
      type: Schema.Types.ObjectId,
      ref: 'users'    
    }
  ],
})

const PostModel = mongoose.model('posts', Post );
export default PostModel ;
```

User Model:

```
import { Schema } from 'mongoose';

const User = new Schema({
  fullname: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  }
})

const UserModel = mongoose.model('users', User);
export default UserModel;
```

My sample data was inserted for Post and User:

```
// ============= Post ==============
[
  {
    ...
    contributer: [
      ObjectId(61aeda1f0420f3cbf1ac8747),
      ObjectId(61aeda360eb472dba01cad4c),
      ObjectId(61aeda3d68a4d7b0d64cc7b1)
    ]
  }
]

// ============= User ==============
[
  {
    _id: ObjectId(61aeda1f0420f3cbf1ac8747),
    fullname: 'Scott',
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(61aeda360eb472dba01cad4c),
    fullname: 'Jason',
  },
  {
    _id: ObjectId(61aeda3d68a4d7b0d64cc7b1),
    fullname: 'Matthew',
  }
]
```

My aggregate to select data:

```
const doc = await PostModel.aggregate([    
  ...    
  {
    "$lookup": {
      "from": "users",  
      "localField": "contributer",  
      "foreignField": "_id",
      "as": "postContributer"
    }
  },  
  ...
])
```

Overal, my expected results like this:

```
[
  {
    ...
    contributer: [
      {
        _id: '61aeda1f0420f3cbf1ac8747',
        fullname: 'Scott',
      },
      {
        _id: '61aeda360eb472dba01cad4c',
        fullname: 'Jason',
      },
      {
        _id: '61aeda3d68a4d7b0d64cc7b1',
        fullname: 'Matthew',
      }
    ],
    ...
  }
]
```

Was I doing it right or not?
Was I doing it right or not?
Was I doing it right or not?
Was I doing it right or not?
Was I doing it right or not?

Anyone have any suggestions for me?
Thankyou!

Comment: If you want it to replace the `contributer` array, use `as: "contributor"`

Comment: @Joe  in your opinion, would my code working right?

Comment: you never showed what that code produced. It looks reasonable.